# Azure DevOps Agent - not able to run

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-container-instances, azure-agent

I am running an Ubuntu self-hosted build agent for Azure DevOps in Container Instances and container outputs only: `Determining matching Azure Pipelines agent.` and that's it.

It has PAT with full access to whole organization, given agent pool really exists and the URL is correct as well. THe only thing that comes to my mind is that I see our URL as `https://XXXX.visualstudio.com/` but I gave the agent url like `https://dev.azure.com/XXX` which still seems to be working when used in the browser.

How to solve this, please?

Comment: hi romanzdk what is the latest status of your issue, does my answer help?

Comment: Sorry, added our solution @CeenoQi-MSFT

Comment: thanks for your sharing to benefit more developers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Agent was put into the subnet which had not NSG, therefore it denied all in/outbound traffic. So we added a NSG to this subnet with outbound rule for port 443 TCP and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your issue is caused by the [agent upgrades to support .NET 6](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/upgrade-of-net-agent-for-azure-pipelines/) (.NET core 3.1 will be out of support in December). You could test to upgrade the container version to 20.04 or higher.

You could also refer to this [issue#3834](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/3834) for more information.